# Representation of Holonomic Constraints by independent generalized coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Say we have a system with N particles described by N position vectors: $\{\vec{r_{i}}\};$ $i=1,...N$

Say we have a holonomic constraint: $$f(\{\vec{r_{i}}\},t)=0 \tag{1}$$
Since we have one holonomic constraint, we will have $3N-1$ independent generalized coordinates to describe the system: $\{q_{j}\};$ $j=1,...3N-1$

Since every position vector is a function of these generalized coordinates:
$$\vec{r_{i}}=\vec{r_{i}}(\{q_{j}\},t)$$  $i=1,...N;j=1,...3N-1$

It means that Equation (1) can be re written as:
$$f(\{q_{j}\},t)=0 \tag{2}$$
But Eq(2) directly implies that $\{q_{j}\}$ is no longer independent. If we specify the values of $q_{1},q_{2}...q_{3N-2}$ and time, the value of $q_{3N-1}$ can be uniquely determined. This goes against the fact that $\{q_{j}\}$ are independent. How to resolve this?

Comment: Hint: Eq. (2) is an identity; not a condition. Try working out a simple low-dimensional example to convince yourself.

Comment: @Qmechanic Got it now. Thnx